# ArrayList not initialised

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I'm just doing some learning and can't see why this ArrayList is initialised but can't be used outside of method its populated within. Can anyone explain? Thanks in advance...

For example if I aske the ArrayList.size() within the method it shows that it has been initialised but elsewhere outside the method it won't.

```
package com.purewowstudio.animations;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.purewowstudio.animations.extras.CustomGrid;
import com.purewowstudio.animations.models.ActorArray;
import com.purewowstudio.animations.models.ActorObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ActorList extends ActionBarActivity {

String LOG_TAG = ActorList.class.getSimpleName();
private ArrayList<ActorObject> actorObjectArrayList;
ActorArray actorArray;
GridView actorGrid;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.actors_list);
    getActors();

    if (actorObjectArrayList != null) {
        ActorObject[] actors = actorObjectArrayList.toArray(new ActorObject[actorObjectArrayList.size()]);

        String actorsNames[] = new String[actorObjectArrayList.size()];
        String actorsImages[] = new String[actorObjectArrayList.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < actorObjectArrayList.size(); i++) {
            actorsNames[i] = actors[i].getName();
            actorsImages[i] = actors[i].getImage();
        }

        CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(ActorList.this, actorsNames, actorsImages);
        actorGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
        actorGrid.setAdapter(adapter);
        actorGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                //Toast.makeText(ActorList.this, "You Clicked at " + actorsNames[+position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.animation_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void getActors(){
    String url ="http://microblogging.wingnity.com/JSONParsingTutorial/jsonActors";
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    actorArray = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(response, ActorArray.class);
                    actorObjectArrayList = actorArray.getActors();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Volley Error");
        }
    });
    queue.add(stringRequest);
}

}
```

Comment: If it's local to the method irs local to the method, that's just how Java works (most languages, I'd say).

Comment: your `getActors` method is asynchronous. By the time you call `actorObjectArrayList != null`, it is not yet initialized, because `public void onResponse(String response)` will be called some time in the future.

Comment: I thought that might have been the case so I took everything from onCreate and added it to it's own method, I then asked that method to start in 10 seconds, still didn't work? What's the que time like with Volley (First time I worked with it). I understand the server response will have a delay

Comment: Can you set a timeout after which, if there's no data in your data structure, you simply either call getActors again or stop the flow because the arraylist is empty?

Comment: I will try this now. Just for learning purposes, is the answer you provided below now suitable for this situation?

Comment: It is my personal opinion that yes, combining what I said in my comment + the answer below should be helpful for your situation ! :)

Comment: Thanks, apologies, I had to reword my comment above. It sounded like I wasn't being appreciative. It's my first time working with Volley so still getting use to it. Do you know if there is a broadcast receiver or similar sort for a call from a Volley thread?

Comment: I have no prior experience with volley. Although, I did found two gems for you that you might appreciate further more. First link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17826914/volley-exception-throws-broadcastreceiver  Second Link:https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why you can't access the content with which you initialized the arraylist in other methods is simple. It is local data inside the scope of the OnCreate. You should define a constructor of your class and initialize the arraylist there. Then in your methods, you can add the data that you need to add. When you'll be looking for data within the arraylist, it will have everything that you're looking for.